# Variable not getting populated after async operation

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `result` variable that is set to `null`. This variable is then passed into `this.GetAsyncData` where an async operation is performed that populates the `results` variable with data.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction()
{
    IEnumerable<object> result = null;
    string fileName;

    switch (type)
    {
        case type1:
            fileName = await this.GetAsyncData(result);
            break;

        default:
            throw new Exception();
    }

    await _call.External(result, fileName);
}

private async Task<string> GetAsyncData(IEnumerable<object> result)
{
    result = await anotherCall();
    return "NewFileName";
}
```

However, in my case, when it reaches `_call.External(result, fileName);`, `result` is always `null`. Even though, when I step through the `this.GetAsyncData`, its getting populated with data.

Comment: It looks like you're going to have to modify `result` through another method. Because you're passing `result` to an async function, you won't be able to pass it by reference and retain changes to it (thanks to @Dai for pointing this out in my now-deleted answer). Once that `GetAsyncData` function ends, `result` will be set back to what you initalized it to, null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not returning the result. I.e., you use it as input parameter. In a normal method, you could use an `out` parameter to return this result, but here, you must use the regular task return value. You can do it by using a [Value Tuple](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/) containing both, the file name and the enumerable:

```
private async Task<(string, IEnumerable<object>)> GetAsyncData()
{
    IEnumerable<object> result = await anotherCall();
    return ("NewFileName", result);
}
```

Usage:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction()
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case type1:
            var (fileName, result) = await this.GetAsyncData();
            break;

        default:
            throw new Exception();
    }

    await _call.External(result, fileName);
}
```

Btw.: you can simply use an `IEnumerable` instead of an `IEnumerable<object>`.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The local variable `result` cannot be changed by the `async GetAsyncData` method because this variable is provided by-value, not by `ref`.

Unfortunately, you cannot use `ref` arguments in `async` methods.

Just use tuples to get both values back (file name and your enumerable).

```
IEnumerable<object> result = null;
string fileName;
(fileName, result) = await this.GetAsyncData();

private async Task<(string, IEnumerable<object>)> GetAsyncData()
{
    var result = await anotherCall();
    return ("NewFileName", result);
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @Spevacus said above, you need to pass `result` by reference, because you are not modifying the collection itself, rather where the variable holding the reference to the collection (you're setting it from null to something non-null).

But unfortunately, async methods cannot have ref or in/out parameters, so perhaps you can do something like:

```
    private async Task<(string, IEnumerable<object>)> GetAsyncData()
    {
        var result = new List<object>();
        return ("NewFileName", result);
    }
```

and call it like:

```
    (fileName, result) = await this.GetAsyncData();
```

Comment: It seems by the time I wrote my answer, it had already been answered. Apologies for double posting! :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing where `result` points (which will have no effect after the method leaves), try adding to it.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction()
{
    List<object> result = new List<object>();  //This is a list now
    string fileName;

    switch (type)
    {
        case type1:
            fileName = await this.GetAsyncData(result);
            break;

        default:
            throw new Exception();
    }

    await _call.External(result, fileName);
}

private async Task<string> GetAsyncData(List<object> result)
{
    result.AddRange( await anotherCall() );   //Add the result of anotherCall() to result
    return "NewFileName";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Async methods can't have ref parameters. You can package your data in the result of your async method using a Tuple or other data structure.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction()
{
    IEnumerable<object> result = null;
    string fileName;

    switch (type)
    {
        case type1:
            Tuple<string, IEnumerable<object>> tuple;
            tuple = await this.GetAsyncData();
            fileName = tuple.Item1;
            result = tuple.Item2;
            break;

        default:
            throw new Exception();
    }

    await _call.External(result, fileName);
}

private async Task<Tuple<string, IEnumerable<object>>> GetAsyncData()
{
    IEnumerable<object> data = await anotherCall();
    string fileName = "NewFileName";
    var tuple = new Tuple<string, IEnumerable<object>>(fileName, data);
    return tuple;
}
```